# SQL Query filter with custom field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below code are use to detect if there exist userid=1 followerid=2 AND userid=2 followerid=1, then the custom column 'bool' will return TRUE.
However, somehow i can't get rid the extra row. 
Any better suggestion or recommendations are appreciated. Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.userid, a.followerid, 
CASE WHEN b.userid=a.followerid AND b.followerid=a.userid 
     THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS bool 
FROM tableUserfollow AS a, tableUserfollow AS b
where a.userid=1
```

tableUserFollow:

```
id  userid  followerid
1       1       2
2       3       4   
3       1       4
4       5       1
5       2       1
```

The output result should be:

```
1   1   2   TRUE
3   1   4   FALSE
```

instead of this:

```
1   1   2   FALSE
1   1   2   TRUE
3   1   4   FALSE
```

Comment: You are not properly joining the two tables. You need to use a JOIN between these two with a proper condition. What you have now is the equivalent of a CROSS JOIN (but in old-school SQL syntax, which is deprecated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if the reciprocal relationship is present, then I think the simplest way is using a correlated subquery, `left join`, or `outer apply`:

```
select uf.*, coalesce(flag, 'FALSE') as 
from tableUserfollow uf outer apply
     (select 'TRUE' as flag
      from tableUserfollow uf2
      where uf2.userId = uf.followerId and uf2.follwerId = uf.userId
     ) f;
```

The `join` would look like:

```
select uf.*,
       (case when uf2.userId is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end)
from tableUserfollow uf left join
     tableUserfollow uf2
     on uf2.userId = uf.followerId and uf2.follwerId = uf.userId
```

Comment: If he doesn't know how to apply a simple join i doubt he will understand this.. you should explain

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks a lot. Perfectly solve my problem. Great!!

Comment: @GordonLinoff And I do understand how your code works, just don't know how to apply in my situation previously. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @Search AS nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @AllFiels Varchar(max);
DECLARE @FixedField Varchar(max);

 SET @FixedField=( SELECT 
    ISNULL(( STUFF( 
    ( 
    SELECT  ', '+(a.value) FROM vwCustomColumns a
    WHERE a.Name  IN (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(CustomReports.ReportFixedFields,',') )
    FOR    XML path('')
    )
    , 1,1,''))  ,'cR.ContractID [Contract ID]') FixedField

    FROM CustomReports WHERE CustomReportId=@CustomReportId )

  SET @AllFiels=@FixedField;


    SET @sql ='SELECT count(*) OVER()  AS Maxcount ,'+@AllFiels+'
    FROM  vwRequestLatest cR 
    INNER JOIN MasterUsers ON MasterUsers.UsersId = cR.Addedby
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RequestTemplate cte ON cte.ContractTemplateId=cR.RequestTemplateId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CountryMaster co ON co.CountryId=cR.CountryId
    ORDER BY
';  

IF (@SortColumn = '') 
BEGIN
    IF (@Direction = 0)
    SET @sql =@sql  + ' cR.RequestId ASC '
    ELSE
    SET @sql =@sql  + ' cR.RequestId DESC '
END
ELSE IF (@SortColumn = 'Request ID') 
BEGIN
    IF (@Direction = 0)
    SET @sql =@sql  + ' cR.RequestId ASC '
    ELSE
    SET @sql =@sql  + ' cR.RequestId DESC '
END

SET @sql =@sql  +'OFFSET ( '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@PageNo)+' - 1 ) * '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@RecordsPerPage)+' ROWS FETCH NEXT '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@RecordsPerPage)+' ROWS ONLY'

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: This View For Custom Field 

        SELECT FieldName AS Name,'rpt.['+FieldName+']' AS value
  FROM CustomDataConfigurator